# Google HA Smart Home Actions - Account getting unlinked automatically

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I have a published Google HA Action, where I have implemented Account Linking using oAuth 2.0 and I can see the server logs when I try to link the Action with my server and it appears to work correctly, I am able to link the Action and also see the success message "Account linked successfully' but immediately after that, when I go to devices, I see them offline & "Not Responding".

I check if it is still linked and poof, its gone. I check my server for any logs, no incoming requests. I check the Google Analytics logs, and again, no logs for any requests. I re-login and re-link the action again from the Google Home app, and same thing happens all over again. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- Hey thanks for reaching out in this regard. We do have some work going on related to this internally and will inform you of the developments once we have an update.
- We do provide a working implementation for account linking in the [Washer Codelab](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer?hl=en#1) and you can try giving it a shot using your credentials to make a successful setup.
- Can you also share your SYNC response after account linking ?